# how to call a function which is passed as parameter in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to call a function which is passed as parameter in another function

**here the function i am calling onclick i paased the fucntion name as parameter**

```
onclick="calldialogbox('thisisfortest')"
```

**this is the function which is calling onclick**

```
function calldialogbox(funtion_name){
    var dialog = $('<p>Are you sure?</p>').dialog({
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function(){
                dialog.dialog('close');
                funtion_name(); //here i am calling function
            },
            "Cancel":  function() {
                dialog.dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**this is the function that is i want to call**

```
function thisisfortest(){
    alert("thisisfortest");
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this one. 
**in html**

```
<a onclick="calldialogbox(thisisfortest)">Click Me</a>
```

**js**

```
function calldialogbox(funtion_name){
var dialog = $('<p>Are you sure?</p>').dialog({
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function(){
            dialog.dialog('close');
            funtion_name(); //here i am calling function
        },
        "Cancel":  function() {
            dialog.dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
}

function thisisfortest(){
alert("thisisfortest");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the function without quotes. This is called callback. In javascript functions are first class objects, so you can pass them around like normal variables.

PS. Try to use addEventListener instead of html onclick attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In case of passing in a function name as parameter - use the following workaround(dealing with 'global' function):

```
...
"Yes": function(){
    dialog.dialog('close');
    window[funtion_name](); //here I'm calling function <----
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking about `function_name` think about it as simply `function` intead - you're not passing in the *name* of the function as a string but an actual reference to the function itself.

```
onclick="calldialogbox(thisisfortest)"
```

You can do this because functions in JavaScript are "first class objects" and can be assigned to variables, passed in as parameters to other functions (aka callbacks), and returned from functions too.

In terms of JS best practice the best way to approach this is to separate out your inline JS using an event listener. Something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="clickable">Click me</div>
```

JS

```
var div = document.getElementById('clickable');
div.addEventListener('click', calldialogbox(thisisfortest), false);
```

That way you don't need the `onclick` event in the HTML.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rn49kdn2/1/)

(Really, because `calldialogbox` isn't an async function, there's really no need to pass that callback in at all in this example.)